# Using Excel 2007 VBA to Add events into Google Calendar

Tags: excel, vba, google-calendar-api

I've sought high and low and been unable to get this functionality working.

All I'm after doing is, in Excel 2007, click a command button, and then VBA does the following:

- Connect to my Google account
- Add an event / or multiple events into my google calendar (not personal, but a second calendar - with private urls/keys/etc)

I've only managed to find couple of "examples" but with slight variances (eg, from MS Access, or using VB IDE)

Can anyone point me towards, or offer, a simple straight forward "Authenticate and Add Event" from Excel VBA?

Apologies for the rather vague question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to us [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) .. try integrating it with excel. Or you can create a connector application which links excel and the app that you created with this API

Comment: Yes, I'm currently trying to use VBA in Excel with the Google Calendar API

Comment: Unfortunately the Google Calendar API documentation does not provide samples for VBA, which the OP seems to be looking for.

1 - https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet